# Actionscript3 - touchevent makes copy

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, touch

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT; 

var chid:DisplayObject;


function onTouchBegin(evt:TouchEvent) { 
evt.target.startTouchDrag(evt.touchPointID); 
chid= DisplayObject(evt.target)
stage.addChild(chid);
} 

function onTouchMove(evt:TouchEvent) { 

} 

function onTouchEnd(evt:TouchEvent) { 
    evt.target.stopTouchDrag(evt.touchPointID); 
}


E1.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin); 
E1.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, onTouchMove); 
E1.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onTouchEnd); 
E3.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin); 
E3.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, onTouchMove); 
E3.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onTouchEnd);  
E2.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin); 
E2.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, onTouchMove); 
E2.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onTouchEnd);
```

I want to convert MouseEvent to touchevent.
It's very simple, just make Touch Drag&Drop, and touched object go to top. But when I touched object, It copy itself...

Can you help me sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
stage.addChild(chid);
```

Why don't you try:

```
chid.parent.setChildIndex(chid, chid.parent.numChildren - 1);
```